# Unable to push to remote git repository with Node-RED

Tags: github, version-control, node-red

I'm currently unable to commit code to GitHub using Node-Red version control. I've set up an empty repository on GitHub for a Node-RED project. In Node-Red I've generated an SSH key and added it my account on GitHub. The repository has also been added to my list of Git remotes in Node-RED.

When trying to clone or push to the repository using my SSH Key and corresponding passphrase the authentication fails. I can connect to the repository and clone it using HTTPS but I can't push to it and get the 'Authentication Required' popup. Are there any checks I can make to resolve the issue and commit my code to the repository?

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: Debugging a problem like this is better suited to the node-red slack or forum - both linked from nodered.org. We can then answer this question here with the eventual resolution for others to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Run `docker exec -it <your_container> ssh git@github.com`, your may see this:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (13.229.188.59)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Enter `yes` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now try to clone or push in your node-red again.

Comment: The server key fingerpints for GitHub (and most of the large git hosting providers) are baked into the Node-RED containers, this should not be required.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2021-08-13, GitHub no longer accepts account passwords when authenticating Git operations (includes GitHub). You need to add a PAT (Personal Access Token) instead, and you can follow the below method to add a PAT on your system.

Creating a personal access token. Log in to your Github & in the upper-right corner of any page, click your profile photo, then click Settings. In the left sidebar, click Developer settings. In the left sidebar, click Personal access tokens. Click Generate new token.

Copy this and paste into password field

Comment: The OP is using SSH keys, they should not require a PAT.